# Get value from JSON with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json

I try to use http://www.codeplex.com/Json to extract values ​​from a json object.

I use imdbapi.com and they return json like this:

```
{"Title": "Star Wars", "Year": "1977", "Rated", "PG", "Released", "25 May 1977", "Genre", "Action, Adventure, Fantasy, Sci-Fi "" Director ":" George Lucas "," Writer "," George Lucas "," Actors ":" Mark Hamill, Harrison Ford, Carrie Fisher, Alec Guinness, "" Plot ":" Luke Skywalker leaves his home planet, teams up With Other Rebels, and Tries to save Princess Leia from the evil clutch of Darth hrs 1 min "," Rating ":" 8.8 "," Votes ":" 397318 "," ID ":" tt0076759 "," Response ":" True "}
```

How can I pick up such title, rating, Year? and save it to my object?

This line return correct json:

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse (json);
```

Now I just need help picking out the data I want. any suggestions?

Answer (score 81):

This should help you http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

```
string json = @"{
    ""Name"": ""Apple"",
    ""Expiry"": new Date(1230422400000),
    ""Price"": 3.99,
    ""Sizes"": [
        ""Small"",
        ""Medium"",
        ""Large""
    ]
}";

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

//This will be "Apple"
string name = (string)o["Name"];
```

Comment: You should test if the key : `o.ContainsKey("Name")`

Answer (score 3):

[JObject API documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)

I believe you are interested in the .Item[key] collection that returns JTokens.

[Full Documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/)

Answer (score 2):

```
class TypeHere{
   string Name {get;set;}
}

TypeHere object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< TypeHere >(jsonString)

// Ex. output 
object.Name;
```