# How to extract only specific attribute from Json

Tags: c#, json

I am getting Json data with multiple attributes but I want to fetch only single out of it

```
[{"Name":"Test","GroupId":"UST","LocationGroupType":"Container","Locale":"en-US","ParentLocationGroup":{"Id":{"Value":4429},,"LgLevel":0,"Users":"0","Admins":"0","Devices":"221","Id":{"Value":5545},"Uuid":"-787d87c8fd3a"}]
```

I want to get `ParentLocationGroup` only, how can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you use a JSON parser? Have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21678495/2436598).

Comment: I'll just put this link into it, because I'm too lazy to give you an example. [Example of SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm)

Comment: @Steve - Now json fixed. pl check

Comment: I think your question is not clear. You can change your server to send only the thing you want. You can use graphql server. If you can't modify the server, you can only filter data in client-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is invalid. No extra comma or missing closing } at the end and you have duplicate key name Id. Your json should be like this.

> [   {
>       "Name": "Test",
>       "GroupId": "UST",
>       "LocationGroupType": "Container",
>       "Locale": "en-US",
>       "ParentLocationGroup": {
>         "LgLevel": 0,
>         "Users": "0",
>         "Admins": "0",
>         "Devices": "221",
>         "Id": {
>           "Value": 5545
>         },
>         "Uuid": "-787d87c8fd3a"
>       }   } ]

And solution...

```
    public class Id
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParentLocationGroup
    {
        public int LgLevel { get; set; }
        public string Users { get; set; }
        public string Admins { get; set; }
        public string Devices { get; set; }
        public Id Id { get; set; }
        public string Uuid { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string GroupId { get; set; }
        public string LocationGroupType { get; set; }
        public string Locale { get; set; }
        public ParentLocationGroup ParentLocationGroup { get; set; }
    }

 string jsonString = "[{\"Name\":\"Test\",\"GroupId\":\"UST\",\"LocationGroupType\":\"Container\",\"Locale\":\"en-US\",\"ParentLocationGroup\":{\"LgLevel\":0,\"Users\":\"0\",\"Admins\":\"0\",\"Devices\":\"221\",\"Id\":{\"Value\":5545},\"Uuid\":\"-787d87c8fd3a\"}}]";

 List<RootObject> roots = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonString);

 ParentLocationGroup parent = roots.FirstOrDefault().ParentLocationGroup;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the string to `JArray` and then parse the first item using `JObject.Parse`

```
var jsonArray = JArray.Parse(jsonstring);
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonArray[0].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(obj["ParentLocationGroup"]);
Console.WriteLine(obj["ParentLocationGroup"]["Id"]["Value"]);
```

Comment: Here I am getting 2 values I need Id only.

Comment: you can access any value within `JObject` . Console.WriteLine(obj["ParentLocationGroup"]["Id"]["Value"]);

Answer (score -1):

Just use Newtonsoft.Json.

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStr);
Console.Write(obj[0].ParentLocationGroup);
```

Note your json root is an array, so hence the obj[0] to just get the first array item.

Comment: dynamic is bad, you should create a class and deserialize into it instead.

Comment: Giving error Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'

Comment: You using C# 4.0 or later? Needed for the dynamic type.