# Capture json data from Steam API

Tags: c#, json, api, steam

So I what I am trying to do is capture/extract specific data from Steams API for dota2 heroes. I am using C# to do this with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010021/get-value-from-json-with-json-net) method.

https://api.steampowered.com/IEconDOTA2_570/GetHeroes/v0001/?key=2D13D618DA712015812E970165632F02&language=en_us

```
{
"result": {
    "heroes": [
        {
            "name": "npc_dota_hero_antimage",
            "id": 1,
            "localized_name": "Anti-Mage"
        },
        ]
}
```

This is the code I have been trying with:

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
        var data = c.DownloadString("https://api.steampowered.com/IEconDOTA2_570/GetHeroes/v0001/?key=2D13D618DA712015812E970165632F02&language=en_us");

        JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);

        string heroname = (string)o["name"];
```

But it only returns an error saying the value of "heroname" is null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`o` is going to be an object that contains one key: `result`.  `o["result"]` will in turn contain a key called `heroes`.  `o["result"]["heroes"]` is an array of objects.  So `o["result"]["heroes"][0]` will be the first item, and `o["result"]["heroes"][0]["name"]` is the name from the first item.